# JSFL export "guides" animations

Tags: flash, animation, ide, flash-cs5, jsfl

I need to convert timeline animations in a FLA into AS3 code (through XML, probably).  The problem is that there are literally hundreds of layers and thousands of frames.

Though I understand JSFL's structure, I am cannot find the "guides" animations by looping down into the timeline->layer->frame.  Using curFrame.isMotionObject() is always false.

Here is a sample of what I am trying to do:

```
/* Gets all motions in all motion objects and exports to a file. */
fl.outputPanel.clear();

//store max layers/frames
var fcnt = fl.getDocumentDOM().getTimeline().frameCount;
var lcnt = fl.getDocumentDOM().getTimeline().layerCount;
fl.trace( "fl.getDocumentDOM().getTimeline().frameCount = " + fcnt );
fl.trace( "fl.getDocumentDOM().getTimeline().layerCount = " + lcnt );

//store pre-run layers/frames:
var origFr = fl.getDocumentDOM().getTimeline().currentFrame;
var origLyr = fl.getDocumentDOM().getTimeline().currentLayer;
fl.trace( "fl.getDocumentDOM().getTimeline().currentFrame = " + origFr );
fl.trace( "fl.getDocumentDOM().getTimeline().currentLayer = " + origLyr );

var totout = 0;
var curFrm;
var curl = origLyr;
var curf = origFr; 
var outstr = "";

for (curf = 0; curf < fcnt; curf++)
{
    // have the IDE go into the current frame:
    fl.getDocumentDOM().getTimeline().currentFrame = curf;

    // removed to test one layer only
    //for (curl = 0; curl < lcnt; curl = lcnt) // curl++) // curl = lcnt)
    //{

        // have the IDE go into the current layer:
        fl.getDocumentDOM().getTimeline().currentLayer = curl;

        if(curf > fl.getDocumentDOM().getTimeline().layers[curl].frames.length)
            break;

        curFrm = fl.getDocumentDOM().getTimeline().layers[curl].frames[curf];

        //this is always false. . . why?
        if (
            curFrm.isMotionObject() 
            //&& curFrm.hasMotionPath()
        ){
            totout++;
            //curFrm.selectMotionPath(true);
        }
        else{
            outstr += "There is no motion path\n";
        }

        //for testing:
        break;
    //}
    //for testing:
    //break;
}

//reset layers/frames back to pre-run status:
fl.getDocumentDOM().getTimeline().currentFrame = origFr;
fl.getDocumentDOM().getTimeline().currentLayer = origLyr;

fl.trace(outstr);
fl.trace("totout = " + totout);
```

Comment: Do you need to export only tweens that us motion paths ? Also, have you tried exporting to the default motion xml ?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?  Not sure what you mean by 'default' motion path . . . did I miss something in the docs?  I think they are all motion paths; would it matter if they were something else?

Comment: well, there's the Classic Tween that can have a motion path applied to it, or not and then there's the Motion Tween, which always has a motion path. If you go to Commands > Export Motion XML I think the xml format is different for the two types of tweens (as far as I remember)

Comment: Ok, that may be true.  But how do I do this through JSFL?  I can easily do it manually, but I have better uses for my wrist than exporting 500 animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Export Motion XML command, which you can call from jsfl via:

```
fl.runScript(fl.configURI + 'Javascript/MotionXML.jsfl', 'exportMotionXML');
```

As far as I remember the [Classic Tween XML](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/motionXSD.html) format is different from the [Motion Tween XML](http://flashthusiast.com/2008/11/04/understanding-flash-cs4-motion-xml/) format. The Motion XML features is quite handy and underused. 
You can use `copyMotionXML` as well and handle the XML in JSFL as the JS engine supports *E4X*.

Alternatively, if you're happy with the Animator/AnimatorFactory classes from the [fl.motion](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/motion/package-detail.html) package, you can do this:

```
fl.runScript(fl.configURI + 'Javascript/MotionXML.jsfl', 'copyMotionAsAS3');
```

Note that the default tween classes are slower than other tween engines, like [TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/), and you also might need to use a timer for the duration of the tween to work out when a tween is finished, so you can gain actionscript access to the tweened object again.

I've used the MotionXML feature a bit at [work for the AudiA8 site](http://disturbmedia.com/#/audi%20a8l) we did as we had to match some interactivity over some beautiful renders from [The Mill](http://www.themill.com/) and I wrote an [importer for Mocha Keyframes](http://disturbmedia.com/george/tests/video_track/motionTrackMochaAE2Flash.swf) to Flash timeline using this feature.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This has led be to what I need: JSFL code for accessing 'guides' and other animations.  In the file **MotionXML.jsfl**, there is a function `MotionXMLExporter.prototype.getXML`.  This is the main FLA processing code in Flash for exporting motion XML from JSFL.  It handles a lot of different animation types, so is pretty complex; I am happy to not have to rewrite this code.  However, it does provide many solutions for drilling down into the FLA and finding data.

Comment: Glad it helps! You can check a Layer's `layerType` property to check if it's a guide layer, or if you want to access 'guidelines' (View > Guides > Show Guides), that should accessible in JSFL via Timeline's `getGuidelines()` function. Check out the [JSFL docs](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=flash_cs5_extending.pdf&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhelp.adobe.com%2Fen_US%2Fflash%2Fcs%2Fextend%2Fflash_cs5_extending.pdf&ei=YW3uTtvPIs3x8QPIq6WCCg&usg=AFQjCNHSRUtg54hM5TlKmDbqNiuFwU_S_A&sig2=oJidGJuJFNvcxhO_QFnJcw) (pdf link) for more details.